# What does "note" mean in "~ said in a note"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

https://www.apnews.com/0e6900537abf41348a48fc64c69085ae

> Brazil’s health ministry says deaths from dengue fever in the last six months have risen 163% from the same period last year.
>
> The ministry said **in a note** Monday that heavier rains and higher temperatures have been contributing factors. It added that dengue has cycles and that the numbers of cases were lower the past two years.

I looked up the dictionary but I'm not sure which definition fits the "note" here. Most of the definitions are related to written/printed texts, but then it doesn't make sense if one *said* "in a note", so I guess note here means something else.

Or does it mean "a brief comment or explanation" ([definition 3-b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/note))?

Comment: written documents "say" things all the time [google result](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NDCM_jaJP718JP719&ei=678mXc6xHsyl8AXauJTAAg&q=%22the+constitution+says%22&oq=%22the+constitution+says%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30l10.8466.10632..10837...0.0..0.116.206.1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0.m01OIleEy_g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Cambridge dictionary, [Note](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/note) defines as:

> "a short letter, or something that you write down in order to remember
>   something."
>
> Example:
>   **note to sb** The bank said in a note to investors that the operation
>   would make strategic sense.

Comment: thanks but I still don't get it, so the ministry official just wrote information on the paper and that paper is a note? And what exactly does "say in a note to~" mean? I guess the example you gave me and mine were used in the same way, but I still don't fully understood it.

Comment: @dbwlsld yes, it could be possible. We usually say, "XYZ says in his book", so why not in a note?